# How to access/save the session data on the authorization event in Socket.io/express-sessions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I setup a websocket using Socket.io and express 4 framework on node.js server.

I am trying to implement authorization step for my users when using my websocket.

When a user connects, a token is passed as a query value to the server. At the server level, I query a database for a session that match the passed token. If a session is found, I do few other check to ensure that the token is not hijacked.

**Problem**

The session data seems to be cleared on every page reload. Or the server is failing to link the sessionId to the user who created it so everytime it generates a new session.

I am puzzled on how to access the session variables "if they are set."

**My Code's Problem**

When a user reload his/her page/client, the session data will become undefined on the new request. The session is good until the page is refreshed which is my problem. I need to be able to keep the session active even after the user refresh their page.

**Questions**

How can ensure that the session data are not cleared on every page refresh?

Here is my authorization code

```
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {

    var session = handshakeData.session || {};

    //This is always undefined!
    console.log('Session Data:' + session.icwsSessionId);

    //var cookies = handshakeData.headers.cookie;
    var token = handshakeData._query.tokenId || '';
    //console.log('Token: ' + token);

    if(!token){
        console.log('Log: token was not found');
        return accept('Token was found.', false);
    }

    //allow any user that is authorized
    if(session && session.autherized && token == session.token){
        console.log('Log: you are good to go');
        return accept('You are good to go', true);
    }

    //if the client changed their token "client logged out"
    //terminate the open session before opening a new one
    if (session.autherized && token != session.token){

        var icwsConnection = new icwsConn(icwsRequest);
        icwsRequest.setConnection(session.icwsServer, session.icwsPort);
        icwsRequest.setIcwsHeaders(session.icwsSessionId, session.icwsToken);
        icwsConnection.logout();

        session.autherized = false;
        session.token = null;
        session.icwsServer = null;
        session.icwsPort = null;
        session.icwsSessionId = null;
        session.icwsToken = null;

        icwsConnection = null;
    }
```

Here is my entire code if needed

```
var env = require('./modules/config'),
    app = require('express')(),
    https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    redisStore = require("connect-redis")(session),
    sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session"),
    base64url = require('base64url');

const server = https.createServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync('certs/key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/cert.pem')
    }, function (req, res){
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
    }
).listen(env.socket.port, env.socket.host, function () {
    console.log('\033[2J');
    console.log('Websocket is running at https://%s:%s', server.address().address, server.address().port);
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

const sessionMiddleware = session({
    store: new redisStore({
        host: env.redis.host,
        port: env.redis.port
    }),
    secret: env.session.secret,
    name: env.session.name,
    rolling: false,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
});

app.use(sessionMiddleware);


// Use shared session middleware for socket.io
// setting autoSave:true
io.use(sharedsession(sessionMiddleware, {
    autoSave: true
})); 


var icwsReq = require('./modules/icws/request.js'),
    icwsConn = require('./modules/icws/connection.js'),
    icwsInter = require('./modules/icws/interactions.js'),
    sessionValidator = require('./modules/validator.js');

var clients = {};
var icwsRequest = new icwsReq();
var sessionChecker = new sessionValidator();



app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('welcome');
});

io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {

    var session = handshakeData.session || {};

    //This is always undefined!
    console.log('Session Data:' + session.icwsSessionId);

    //var cookies = handshakeData.headers.cookie;
    var token = handshakeData._query.tokenId || '';
    //console.log('Token: ' + token);

    if(!token){
        console.log('Log: token was not found');
        return accept('Token was found.', false);
    }

    //allow any user that is authorized
    if(session && session.autherized && token == session.token){
        console.log('Log: you are good to go');
        return accept('You are good to go', true);
    }

    /*
    if (!originIsAllowed(origin)) {
        // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
        socket.destroy();
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + origin + ' rejected.');
        return false;
    }
    */

    //if the client changed their token "client logged out"
    //terminate the open session before opening a new one
    if (session.autherized && token != session.token){

        var icwsConnection = new icwsConn(icwsRequest);
        icwsRequest.setConnection(session.icwsServer, session.icwsPort);
        icwsRequest.setIcwsHeaders(session.icwsSessionId, session.icwsToken);
        icwsConnection.logout();

        session.autherized = false;
        session.token = null;
        session.icwsServer = null;
        session.icwsPort = null;
        session.icwsSessionId = null;
        session.icwsToken = null;

        icwsConnection = null;
    }

    var myIP = '10.0.4.195';

    var decodedToken = base64url.decode(token);

    sessionChecker.validateData(decodedToken, myIP, env.session.duration, function(isValid, icws){

        if(isValid){

            session.authorized = true;
            session.icwsServer = icws.host;
            session.icwsPort = icws.port;
            session.token = token;
            session.icwsSessionId = null;
            session.icwsToken = null;

            icwsRequest.setConnection(icws.host, icws.port);
            var icwsConnection = new icwsConn(icwsRequest);

            icwsConnection.login(icws.username, icws.password, function(isLogged, icwsSession, headers){

                if(isLogged && icwsSession.sessionId && icwsSession.csrfToken){

                    //icwsConnection.setWorkstation(icws.workstaton);
                    session.icwsSessionId = icwsSession.sessionId;
                    session.icwsToken = icwsSession.csrfToken;

                    icwsRequest.setIcwsHeaders(session.icwsSessionId, session.icwsToken);
                    console.log('Log: new connection to ICWS! ' + session.icwsSessionId );
                }

            });

            console.log('Log: new connection to websocket!')
            return accept('New connection to websocket!', true);

        } else {

            console.log('Log: token could not be validated!');
            return accept('Token could not be validated!', false);
        }

    });

});


io.on('connection', function (socket) { 


    console.log('Authorized Session! Websocket id ready for action!');
    //var origin = socket.request.headers.origin || '';
    //var myIP = socket.request.socket.remoteAddress || '';

    if(!socket.request.sessionID){
        console.log('Missing Session ID');
        return false;
    }

    var socketId = socket.id;
    var sessionID = socket.request.sessionID;


    //Add this socket to the user's connection
    if(userCons.indexOf(socketId) == -1){
        userCons.push(socketId);
    }

    clients[sessionID] = userCons;

    console.log(clients); //display all connected clients

    socket.on('placeCall', function(msg){

        icwsInter.call(method, uri, params, header, true);

    });

    socket.on('chat', function(msg){
        console.log('Chat Message: ' + msg);
        socket.emit('chat', { message: msg });
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function(msg){
        console.log('Closing sessionID: ' + sessionID);
        var userCons = clients[sessionID] || [];

        var index = userCons.indexOf(socketId);

        if(index > -1){
            userCons.splice(index, 1);
            console.log('Removed Disconnect Message: ' + msg);
        } else {
            console.log('Disconnect Message: ' + msg);
        }

    }); 

    socket.on('error', function(msg){
        console.log('Error Message: ' + msg);
    }); 

});


function originIsAllowed(origin) {
    // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
        var allowed = env.session.allowedOrigins || []

        if(allowed.indexOf(origin) >= 0){
            return true;
        }

    return false;
}
```

**Edited**

The `io` cookie changes on every request. When a `io` cookie is created it will have a last accessed values of `12/31/1969 4:00:00 PM`

Also, this cookie changes on every page reload.

After @Osk suggestion below Here is my new code which is still isn't saving my session data on page reload.

```
var env = require('./modules/config'),
    app = require('express')(),
    https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    redisStore = require("connect-redis")(session),
    sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session"),
    base64url = require('base64url'),
    cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const server = https.createServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync('certs/key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/cert.pem')
    }, function (req, res){
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
    }
).listen(env.socket.port, env.socket.host, function () {
    console.log('\033[2J');
    console.log('Websocket is running at https://%s:%s', server.address().address, server.address().port);
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var sessionStore = new redisStore({
        host: env.redis.host,
        port: env.redis.port
    });

const sessionMiddleware = session({
        store: sessionStore,
        secret: env.session.secret,
        name: env.session.name,
        rolling: true,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: { 
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000
        }
    });


app.use(sessionMiddleware);

// Use shared session middleware for socket.io
// setting autoSave:true
io.use(sharedsession(sessionMiddleware, {
    autoSave: false
})); 

var icwsReq = require('./modules/icws/request.js'),
    icwsConn = require('./modules/icws/connection.js'),
    icwsInter = require('./modules/icws/interactions.js'),
    sessionValidator = require('./modules/validator.js');

var clients = {};

var icwsRequest = new icwsReq();
var sessionChecker = new sessionValidator();



app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('welcome');
});


//Middleware for authorizing a user before establishing a connection
io.use(function(socket, next) {


    var origin = socket.request.headers.origin || '';

    if (!originIsAllowed(origin)) {
        // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
        socket.destroy();
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + origin + ' rejected.');
        return false;
    }

    var myIP = socket.request.socket.remoteAddress || '';
    var token = socket.handshake.query.tokenId || '';
    var session = socket.handshake.session || {};

    //This should be defined on a reload
    console.log('IP Address: ' + myIP + '      SessionID: ' + socket.handshake.sessionID);

    if(!token){
        console.log('Log: token was not found');
        return next(new Error('Token not found'));
    }

    //allow any user that is authorized
    if(session && session.autherized && token == session.token){
        console.log('Log: you are good to go');
        return next(new Error('You are good to go'));
    }

    //if the client changed their token "client logged out"
    //terminate the open session before opening a new one
    if (session.autherized && token != session.token){

        var icwsConnection = new icwsConn(icwsRequest);
        icwsRequest.setConnection(session.icwsServer, session.icwsPort);
        icwsRequest.setIcwsHeaders(session.icwsSessionId, session.icwsToken);
        icwsConnection.logout();

        session.autherized = false;
        session.token = null;
        session.icwsServer = null;
        session.icwsPort = null;
        session.icwsSessionId = null;
        session.icwsToken = null;
        icwsConnection = null;
        session.save();
    }

    var decodedToken = base64url.decode(token);

    sessionChecker.validateData(decodedToken, myIP, env.session.duration, function(isValid, icws){

        if(isValid){

            session.authorized = true;
            session.icwsServer = icws.host;
            session.icwsPort = icws.port;
            session.token = token;
            session.icwsSessionId = null;
            session.icwsToken = null;

            icwsRequest.setConnection(icws.host, icws.port);
            var icwsConnection = new icwsConn(icwsRequest);
            /*
            icwsConnection.login(icws.username, icws.password, function(isLogged, icwsSession, headers){

                if(isLogged && icwsSession.sessionId && icwsSession.csrfToken){

                    //icwsConnection.setWorkstation(icws.workstaton);
                    session.icwsSessionId = icwsSession.sessionId;
                    session.icwsToken = icwsSession.csrfToken;

                    icwsRequest.setIcwsHeaders(session.icwsSessionId, session.icwsToken);
                    console.log('Log: new connection to ICWS! ' + session.icwsSessionId );
                }

            });
            */
            session.save(function(){
                console.log('Log: new connection to websocket!');   
            });

            return next();

        } else {

            console.log('Log: token could not be validated!');
            return next(new Error('Token could not be validated!'));
        }

    });

});


io.on('connection', function (socket) { 

    console.log('Connection is validated and ready for action!');

    var socketId = socket.id;

    if(!socket.handshake.sessionID){
        console.log('sessionId was not found');
        return false;
    }

    var sessionID = socket.handshake.sessionID;
    var userCons = clients[sessionID] || [];

    //Add this socket to the user's connection
    if(userCons.indexOf(socketId) == -1){
        userCons.push(socketId);
    }

    clients[sessionID] = userCons;

    //console.log(clients);

    socket.on('placeCall', function(msg){

        icws.call(method, uri, params, header, true);

    });

    socket.on('chat', function(msg){
        console.log('Chat Message: ' + msg);
        socket.emit('chat', { message: msg });
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function(msg){
        console.log('Closing sessionID: ' + sessionID);
        var userCons = clients[sessionID] || [];

        var index = userCons.indexOf(socketId);

        if(index > -1){
            userCons.splice(index, 1);
            console.log('Removed Disconnect Message: ' + msg);
        } else {
            console.log('Disconnect Message: ' + msg);
        }

    }); 

    socket.on('error', function(msg){
        console.log('Error Message: ' + msg);
    }); 

});


function originIsAllowed(origin) {
    // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
        var allowed = env.session.allowedOrigins || []

        if(allowed.indexOf(origin) >= 0){
            return true;
        }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you try use something like passport or logic like passport.socket-io? (https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio/blob/master/lib/index.js)

Comment: @AndrewParamoshkin I did not. but I am using `express-socket.io-session` to share the session.

Comment: your session data really writen in database? client-side writes cookies and did request have cookies header?

Comment: @AndrewParamoshkin yes the session info are stored in a database.I am not sure about your other question.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of socket.io are you using?

**express-socket.io-session** works with socket.io 1.x

I see you're calling `io.set()` which is deprecated on socket.io 1.x

For more on this, take a look at http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/ under the title Authentication differences. 
There, it's stated that

> The old `io.set()` and `io.get()` methods are deprecated and only
>   supported for backwards compatibility."

Could this be related to your issue ?

When you install the express-socket.io-session package, there's an example directory inside the package. It may come in handy to test against a working example for this module.

Comment: Hi Osk, I am using v1.3.6. As per your suggestion I change the io.set to io.use. I will update the question with my new code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of how you can share sessions between express and socket.io, even when they are not on the same domain.

(You can find a slightly different git repository with a running example here https://github.com/dievardump/express-socket-auth )

I simply use `express-session`, I don't see why using another middleware, since it works perfectly with socket.io

Since I do not have `redis` accessible, I used `require('session-file-store')` for the shared sessions.

**Problem**

Problem comes from the `cross-domain` policy which won't let you share the `connect.sid` Cookie value.

A workaround is :

- serve non-httpOnly session cookies from the host (here for me `server.dev`). **[express.js line 16]**
- read via JavaScript and send the `connect.sid` value as a `sessionId` parameter when connection to `socket.io` **[client.js line 26:30]**
- when handshaking adding the value of `connect.sid=socket.handshake.query.sessionId` to the `socket.handshake.headers.cookie` before reading the handshake with the session middleware **[socket.js line 32:37]**

**Architecture**

Here followed :

- server.js which require

  - express.js : Create express server accessed on my computer via `http://server.dev:3000`

    - serve HTML
    - create Sessions when loading page
  - socket.js : Create Socket.io server accessed on my computer via `http://socket.dev:8000`
- client.js

  - served on `http://server.dev:3000`
  - connect to socket server on `http://socket.dev:8000`

**Tests**

Steps to test I used here :

- Client open the page
- If the cookie key `connect.sid` is not set

  - Client tries to connect to `Socket.io` : Connection error : [Not authenticated]
  - Client calls `/authenticate`

    - session is generated
  - Client tries to connect to `Socket.io` with value of `connect.sid` as `sessionId` parameter : Connection sucessfull
- If cookie `connect.sid` is set

  - Client tries to connect to `Socket.io` with value of `connect.sid` as `sessionId` parameter  : Connection sucessfull

**Files**

*server.js*

```
require('./express');
require('./socket');
```

*express.js*

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sessionExpress = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(sessionExpress);

var secret = 'keyboard cat';
var session = sessionExpress({
    secret: secret,
    store: new FileStore(),
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { 
        httpOnly: false, // important to allow client to read session cookie with JavaScript
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.use('/authenticate', session);
app.get('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
    var session = req.session;
    session.userdata = session.userdata || {};
    session.userdata.connected = true;
    session.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            connectionError(res, session);
        } else {
            res.status(200);
            res.send();
        }
    });
});

// routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('welcome');
});

// setup servers
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
```

*socket.js*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');
var sessionExpress = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(sessionExpress);

var secret = 'keyboard cat';
var sessionIdKey = 'connect.sid';

var session = sessionExpress({
    secret: secret,
    store: new FileStore(),
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { 
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000
    }
});

// setup servers
var server = http.createServer(app, function (req, res){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
});

server.listen(8000);

var sio = io(server);
sio.use(function(socket, accept) {        
    // writing sessionId, sent as parameter, on the socket.handshake cookies
    if (socket.handshake.query.sessionId) {
        var cookies = (socket.handshake.headers.cookie || '').split(';');
        cookies.push(sessionIdKey + '=' + socket.handshake.query.sessionId);
        socket.handshake.headers.cookie = cookies.join(';');
    }
    session(socket.handshake, {}, function(err) {
        if (err) return accept(err);
        console.log('User trying to connect to Socket.io');
        var session = socket.handshake.session,
            userData = session.userdata || {};

        // is connected and good
        if (!userData || !userData.connected) {
            console.log('----- User has no active session, error');
            accept(new Error('Not authenticated'));
        } else {
            console.log('----- Socket.io connection attempt successful');
            accept(null, session.userid !== null);
        }
    });
});


sio.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Connection');
});
```

*client.js*

```
        function getCookie(name) {
            var value = "; " + document.cookie;
            var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
            if (parts.length == 2) return decodeURIComponent(parts.pop().split(";").shift());
        }

        function fetch(url, data, callback) {
            try {
                var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
                x.open(data ? 'POST' : 'GET', url, 1);
                x.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
                x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                x.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    x.readyState > 3 && callback && callback(x.responseText, x);
                };
                x.send(data || null);
            } catch (e) {
                window.console && console.log(e);
            }
        };


        function connectServer(cb) {
            var sessionId = getCookie('connect.sid');
            var data = { forceNew: true, query : {  } };
            if (sessionId) {
                data.query.sessionId = sessionId
            }

            console.log('Trying to connect to Socket.io server');

            var server = io('http://socket.dev:8000', data);
            server.on('error', function (err) {
                console.log('----- Connection error : [%s]', err);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    cb();
                }, 200);
            });
            server.on('connect', function (data) {
                console.log('----- Connection successful with sessionId [%s]', sessionId);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    cb();
                }, 200);
            });
        }

        if (getCookie('connect.sid')) {
            console.log('Session cookie Detected');
            connectServer(function () { });
        } else {
            connectServer(function () {
                console.log('Call ./authenticate to create session server side');
                fetch('./authenticate', null, function () {
                    console.log('Session created')
                    connectServer(function () {});
                }); 
            }); 
        }
```

**Execution**

*First Page loading Results*

Client :

```
Trying to connect to Socket.io server
----- Connection error : [Not authenticated]
Call ./authenticate to create session server side
Session created
Trying to connect to Socket.io server
----- Connection successful with sessionId [s:Ir9dVPi8wzplPCoeNXAsDlOkhL8AW0gx.wwzUQ2jftntWEc6lRdYqGxRBoszjPtjT4dBW/KjFIXQ]
```

Server :

```
User trying to connect to Socket.io
----- User has no active session, error
User trying to connect to Socket.io
----- Socket.io connection attempt successful
Connection
```

*Reload page*

Client :

```
Session cookie Detected
Trying to connect to Socket.io server
----- Connection successful with sessionId [s:Ir9dVPi8wzplPCoeNXAsDlOkhL8AW0gx.wwzUQ2jftntWEc6lRdYqGxRBoszjPtjT4dBW/KjFIXQ]
```

Server :

```
User trying to connect to Socket.io
----- Socket.io connection attempt successful
Connection
```

Comment: I think the problem is what when a user connect to the websocket from a different server the session will not be saved. Remember that the user who connects to my websocket they send the request from a different server not from express. Please take a look at this question which explain the exact problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728900/how-to-create-a-handshake-between-php-web-server-and-socket-io-on-node-js-server

Comment: I updated my answer with a shared session between express (who create the sessions) on port `3000` and socket.io (who read the shared sessions) on port `8000`, both created in different files

Comment: Hi, thank you for the edit. I am not sure that I follow your code. So the client will have to send a user name to express at port 3000 which will generate a token and it will send it back to the client. Then the client will make a connection to socket.io at port 8000 and does the communication, correct?

Comment: The different things with the `token` where to show how the connection can be refused, without invalidating the session. What is important is how to make the socket server and the express server share the session, even without being on the same domain. 1/ non httpOnly session cookies 2/ read cookies from client and send them as param when connecting to socket server 3 / modify cookie before reading the handshake with the session middleware

Comment: sorry I am having hard time trying to understand the code or the workaround. it would be easier if you only explain to me the handshake step which is what I am missing.

Comment: As you asked, I edited again, but you'll have to understand what I wrote (in the explicatio and the code) because I won't be able to do more simple.

Comment: I am trying to to your example to work. The only thing I changes in run the socket/express using https instead of http and run it on 10.0.4.18 instead of the local host so I can get to the node from my other server. but still unable to get it to work

Comment: any chance you have a working example I can run and works? the client must be from a different physical server and express/socket should be on the same node.js server

Comment: if you run what I gave you, it will work. At least it work for me.

Comment: When you got it to work, is the client code running from a separate server?

Comment: client coe is just the JavaScript that you have to put in a HTML file, with a script tag inserting the cleint `socket.io.js`

Comment: Can you please help me understand the following lines of code? in the express file `app.use(express.static(__dirname));   app.use('/authenticate', session);`  also in the socket.js `session(socket.handshake, {}, function(err) {`  what exactly are you doing there? what exactly are you passing there and why?  How does the '/authenticate` route creates the connect.sid cookie?

Comment: I added a github repository with a working example. Just clone it, and follow the readme. Sources are commented where you asked for explainations

Comment: thank you so much for taking your time to create the github repository. I want to make sure I explained what I am trying to do correctly. I don't care about express environment. all I care about is running socket, then be able to connect to it from HTML code that is running on Apache Server. My HTML code will connect to the socket, socket will need to store user data in the session. If a user opens 5 browser's tabs with the same HTML code, I am expecting that the socket will **re-use** the session data already created. is this what you accomplished in the example?