# How to create a handshake between PHP web server and Socket.io on node.js server?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express, socket.io

I have a websocket running on node.js 4.0 on server 10.0.4.18 at port 8020. I implemented my websocket using socket.io v1.3, express, and express-session.

**Project Definition**

I need to be able to create a session in socket.io for every user that connects to it from a PHP application. After the user send the first HTTP request, I will authenticate them using a token that will be passed from PHP to socket.io along with the HTTP request.

After the user is authenticated, I need to save some personal data inside socket.io session to reuse later. Every time the user refresh the PHP application, socket.io will need to know the session data that is already created.

**Problem**

Every time the user reloads/refreshed the PHP page "where he/she connected from", the session data are lost. The server fails to know that connection belong to session XYZ which is previously created created.

I am not sure how to create a handshake between PHP and node.js where the two server can exchange a unique data to tie the socket.io session to.

**Very close look at the problem**

I opened this link https://10.0.4.18:8020/set/MikeA in my browser. "This created a session for me directly from node.js per the route code"

Then I connected to the websocket using PHP, now I can see that the session sticks with no problem! I was able to open multiple tabs in the browser and the same session is there as expected.

The reason it worked this time is because the url https://10.0.4.18:8020/set/MikeA established a session and tied it between my browser and the session and from there I was able to read/write my session from socket.io using express-socket.io-session package https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session.

But if I do not create the session using the url manually the session will only be good for one page load only. And every time the page is reloaded the session is destroyed like it never existed!

**Question**

I need to develop the same behavior when connection to the websocket via https://10.0.4.18:8020/set/MikeA when connecting from the socket.io.

How can I establish a handshake between PHP server and socket.io where the two servers can tie the session data to the correct user every time the PHP page is reloaded or a new browser's tab is opened?

Here is my websocket code

```
var app = require('express')(),
    https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session"),
    fileStore = require('session-file-store')(session),
    base64url = require('base64url'),
    cookieParser = require("cookie-parser"),
    env = require('./modules/config');


var server = https.createServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync('certs/key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/cert.pem')
    }, app).listen(env.socket.port, env.socket.host, function () {
    console.log('\033[2J');
    console.log('Websocket is running at https://%s:%s', server.address().address, server.address().port);
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var icwsReq = require('./modules/icws/request.js'),
    icwsConn = require('./modules/icws/connection.js'),
    icwsInter = require('./modules/icws/interactions.js'),
    sessionValidator = require('./modules/validator.js');

var icwsRequest = new icwsReq();
var sessionChecker = new sessionValidator();

var sessionStoreFile = new fileStore({path: './tmp/sessions'});

var clients = {};

var sessionOptions = {
        store: sessionStoreFile,
        secret: env.session.secret,
        name: env.session.name,
        rolling: true,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        resave: true,
        unset: 'keep',
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000
        }
    };

var sessionMiddleware = session(sessionOptions);

app.use(sessionMiddleware); // session support for the app


//Set access control headers on every express route.
app.use(function (req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
    next();
});


// Use shared session middleware for socket.io
io.use(sharedsession(sessionMiddleware, {
    autoSave: true
})); 

//Middleware for authorizing a user before establishing a connection
io.use(function(socket, next) {

    var myIP = socket.request.socket.remoteAddress || '';
    var token = socket.handshake.query.tokenId || '';
    var session = socket.handshake.session || {};

    if(!session && !token){
        console.log('Log: No session and no token!');
        return next(new Error('No tken/session found'));
    }

    if(!token){
        console.log('Log: token was not found');
        return next(new Error('Token not found'));
    }

    //SessionID should be defined on a page reload
    console.log('IP Address: ' + myIP + '      SessionID: ' + socket.handshake.sessionID);

    //allow any user that is authorized
    if(session && session.autherized && token == session.token){
        console.log('Log: you are good to go');
        return next(new Error('You are good to go'));
    }

    //if the client changed their token "client logged out"
    //terminate the open session before opening a new one
    if (session.autherized && token != session.token){

    var decodedToken = base64url.decode(token);

    sessionChecker.validateData(decodedToken, myIP, env.session.duration, function(isValid, icws){

        if(!isValid){
            console.log('Log: token could not be validated!');
            return next(new Error('Token could not be validated!'));
        }

        session.authorized = true;
        session.icwsServer = icws.host;
        session.icwsPort = icws.port;
        session.token = token;
        session.icwsSessionId = null;
        session.icwsToken = null;

        icwsRequest.setConnection(icws.host, icws.port);
        var icwsConnection = new icwsConn(icwsRequest);

        session.save(function(){
            console.log('Log: new connection to websocket!');
            return next();
        });
    });

});


io.on('connection', function (socket) { 

    console.log('Connection is validated and ready for action!');

    var socketId = socket.id;

    if(!socket.handshake.sessionID){
        console.log('sessionId was not found');
        return false;
    }

    var sessionID = socket.handshake.sessionID;
    var userCons = clients[sessionID] || [];

    //Add this socket to the user's connection
    if(userCons.indexOf(socketId) == -1){
        userCons.push(socketId);
    }

    clients[sessionID] = userCons;

    socket.on('chat', function(msg){

        for (var key in clients[sessionID]) {
          if (clients[sessionID].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var id = clients[sessionID][key];
            console.log('Client Said: ' + msg);
            io.to(id).emit('chat', {message: 'Server Said: ' + msg});
          }
        }
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', function(msg){
        console.log('Closing sessionID: ' + sessionID);
        var userCons = clients[sessionID] || [];

        var index = userCons.indexOf(socketId);

        if(index > -1){
            userCons.splice(index, 1);
            console.log('Removed Disconnect Message: ' + msg);
        } else {
            console.log('Disconnect Message: ' + msg);
        }

    }); 

    socket.on('error', function(msg){
        console.log('Error Message: ' + msg);
    }); 

});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('welcome: ' + req.sessionID);
});

app.get('/read', function (req, res) {
    res.send('welcome: ' + req.session.name);
});

app.get('/set/:name', function (req, res) {
    req.session.name = req.params.name;
    res.send('welcome: ' + req.session.name);
});
```

Here is how I connect to the websocket from PHP server

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>

    <script src="https://10.0.4.18:8020/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function(){
            var socket = io.connect('https://10.0.4.18:8020', {secure: true, port: 8020,  query : 'PHP generated token that will be used to authenticate the user from node.js'});

           //When the "send" button is clicked
            $('#f').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var message = $('#m').val().trim();
                if( message  == ''){
                    return false;
                }

                socket.emit('chat', message);
                $('#m').val('');
            });

            socket.on('chat', function(msg){
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg.message));
            });

        });

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="" id="f">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible since when the page is reloaded or the browsers travels to a different one all of the JavaScript instances die since they are unique per page and a new socket connection needs to be established, if you want to identify the user from the new connection the best way is to work with sessions , when the user logs in or connects for the first time, a unique session id is created and sent from the server to the user and stored locally, so each time the client start a new connection, it identifies it self with the session id to the server and the server should recoginze

Comment: @DanielMendel How would I pass the session back to the client? From the node.js server, how would I load a specific sessionID after the first request?

Answer (score 2):

Store the token in the browser and send it along with every request from the php, with an authorization bearer which looks like :

```
Authorization: Bearer token
```

So everytime the node.js server get's an request you can compare the token to which user corresponds and get the data.

You can store the relationship between the userid and the token with an expiry date in a table and refresh the token on every login.

Also if you don't want to use a table, you can store the data in the token, with JWT

You can find more info here:

http://jwt.io/

Comment: I'm totally agree with Alex7, in fact previously i joined php sessions with socket.io node , and it's working  good for me , but i had a lot of coupled code attached to a physic php session in a server .. and that's is a scalability problem , another reason is.. if you can write uncoupled backend responses in for example Json format , you can render the view using the client performance instead using server to send the response views in every request... and it will improve the performance and also you can package it in app more quickly ( like ionic , phonegap ,react etc..)

Comment: @Alex7 Thank you for your feedback. If I understand you correctly, I should have a relational object on my node.js that keeps a relation  between the sessionID and the token passed in the header. Then in the middleware I add a check, if the token already exists then load existing session. If not, generate a new session and store it in the relations object. But, how would I force express-session to generate a new sessionID?

Comment: @MikeA i think you are looking for Session.regenerate() which you can find here https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionregenerate. But here are 2 scenarios: First, you make the key expire after 1 hour and you need regeneration to not keep the user login again and again, Second you make the session expire after 1 week when the user must login again and you don't need the regeneration, you just create a new session. You can create an mechanism so when you upgrade the app, you delete the object that stores the sessionID and token and all users must login again so you don't have old data.

Comment: @Alex7, I tried to use regenerate() but it is not working. I get this error `socket.session.regenerate(function(err) {                       ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'regenerate' of undefined     at Array.<anonymous>`

Comment: @MikeA i am not very familiar with node but from what i understood from their documentation i believe that the session regeneration must be done on the request like req.session.regenerate. i am not sure if your socket is equivalent with their req variable from their examples. Maybe you generate the session with req.session and you save it in socket.session. So to regenerate it you must do kind of the same thing. I am not sure i can help you any further with this, hope it helps